# Does ArcGIS Online have version number?

Tags: arcgis-online

Does ArcGIS Online have a version or is it only referenced by Month/Year, which is all I see on [What's new](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/whats-new.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_89E235B166034297BB30108303512485)?

Is there a compatibility matrix that shows the ArcGIS Online releases with their compatible ArcGIS Desktop versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a version available indeed. Go to:

```
http://%youragolorg%.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest?f=json
```

This would give you:

```
{"currentVersion":"3.9"}
```

This information is accessible via REST API, look for [Root](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Root/02r30000009t000000/) in case you want to access this information programmatically. Check the [ArcREST](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/) Python package for administering your ArcGIS Online or Portal organization; I use it daily for about half a year, couldn't be more happy about it.

I don't think there is a matrix that says "you can publish features from ArcGIS 10.2 to AGOL 3.7+" though. What we do know though, is that starting with 10.1, you can publish to ArcGIS Online (in 10.0 there was no menu File > Share As > Service). So if you are on 10.1+, you are safe, as there were no changes in the architecture starting with 10.1 except being able to consume more resources (such as ready-to-use services).

Comment: I'm interested in ArcMap Consuming  AGOL from ArcMap 10.1, which does not work (it used to).  ArcMap 10.2.1/10.3 works fine.  I think we can raise minimum ArcMap version to 10.2.x, but knowing what breaks would help for planning future ArcMap AddIn releases.

Comment: @JayCummins, I see. You have developed a custom add-in in ArcMap (Python or .NET?) and consume AGOL services within it? It's super hard to guess what could be wrong, but I am surprised to hear that 10.1 doesn't work when the 10.2.1 does. What exactly doesn't work from ArcMap 10.1?

Comment: The `Add Data From ArcGIS Online..` ➡ `Add` isn't working in 10.1 for us.  This is without the AddIn (my AddIn will see the added data as whatever ILayer, no issues there).   After pressing `Add`, the ArcGIS window closes and there is no error shown and no data added.   When a debugger is attached, I do get an error inside an Esri library.  I took a screenshot, I'll post a link of the stack when I get to work.

Comment: This may become a non-issue for us--we are 98% certain that the few remaining customers 10.1 can be upgraded to 10.2.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30815/arcmap-10-1-add-data-arcgisonline-problem